# MySQL REGEXP statement returning true when it shouldn't?

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT 
'8 / 10 Valle Seti'
REGEXP
'([1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]) (Valle Seti)'
```

This returns 1 in mysql. How is that possible? I am only specifying two digits greater than 10, followed by a word, but this is matching a single digit, followed by a slash, then a two digit number. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is matching

```
'10 Valle Seti'
```

from

```
'8 / 10 Valle Seti'
```

To force the regex to start and end at the string ends, change it to

```
REGEXP
'^([1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]) (Valle Seti)$'
```

Answer (score 2):

because it founds a match on the string (*which is `10 Valle Seti`*), try adding assert `beginning` and `end` character

```
SELECT 
'8 / 10 Valle Seti'
REGEXP
'(^[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]) (Valle Seti)$'
```

See [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2653)